Circular dependency in Mono Repo
I have the following circular dependency problem
There is a monorepo let's say "Main_Repo" (on gitlab).

One of the applications within "Main_Repo" is a fast api application (let's say job_manager) which generates an api let's say "api_client"

There is another application within "Main_Repo" let's say "runtime_app" that uses a package (lets say "user_of_api_client") from another Github repo which uses the "api_client".


So the problem is

In ci/cid pipeline, there is a stage that publishes "api_client" to it github repo
In another job (which runs after the publish job), an end to end test runs (and fails) where "runtime_app" uses "user_of_api_client" package which is still using
older version of "api_client". So there is this circular dependency.

What we do now to work around is as follows

The "Main_Repo" MR publishes a new "api_client" on github
The end to end tests fail (which breaks the "Main_Repo" pipeline)
We manually release "api_client" to pypi which has its own release pipleine
When the "api_client" version is published on pypi, we manually update "api_client" version in "user_of_api_client", raise a PR(Github), approve and merge
when "user_of_api_client" PR is approved, merged, we raise a new MR in "Main_Repo" to update "user_of_api_client" hash in "runtime_app" ' dependencies,
approve and merge and this finally fixes the (broken) pipeline

Any thoughts how this can be fixed or atleast improved

In the workaround step 1 and 3 you say that as part of the pipieline the new api_client is published to github and later manually released to PyPI? Why both? Is only one source used to get the api_client by apps like the user_of_api_client or both are by different apps?

The clean solution
Since the user_of_api_client is accessible to your team already (maybe even owned?), the cleanest solution would probably be to integrate it into your monorepo Main_Repo as well. (Afterall having a monorepo should be a solution to dependency problems.)
Whenever you build a new api_client you could bump up the api_client version in user_of_api_client in the same commit. Then you could squash in the rebuild of the user_of_api_client at the appropriate place in the pipeline.

Publish api_client.
Build the user_of_api_client with the new api_client version. Update the hash in runtime_app dependencies.
Run E2E tests (like the runtime_app tests).

This would require you to merge your GitHub repository into your GitLab monorepo.

Have good documentation
Sometimes having architecture and processes very well drawn out makes improvements almost obvious. And it's incredibly helpful to make fellows (like coworkers or StackOverflow people) comprehend the situation.
A good diagram would be a huge win.

Another improvement could be automating parts or all of the process. You'll know best what's possible here, so the following is just brainstorming.
Automate step 4 of the workaround
Update the api_client version in the user_of_api_client GitHub repo automatically from within your GitLab pipeline by using a GitHub personal access token to check out the whole user_of_api_client repository and modify the api_client version number there with bash commands, like the sed command. Then push it. (Keep in mind the GitLab Runner executing this determines the shell dialect.)
jobnameXYZ:
  script:
    # Install Git if not already installed on the GitLab Runner
    - apk add -q git

    # Clone the `user_of_api_client` project | The ${} is a GitLab CI/CD secret
    - git clone https://oauth2:${GITHUB_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN}/path...

    # Modify some file version.txt
    - echo "versionNumber: 2.1" > version.txt

    # Cd in checked out project and configure an arbitrary user email and name because git does not allow anonymous commits
    - cd "user_of_api_client"
    - git config user.email "user@xyz.com"
    - git config user.name "user"

    # Stage, Commit and Push those changes
    - git add .
    - git commit -m "bump up api client version"
    - git push https://oauth2:${GITHUB_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN}/path... main


Make the process look less like an error and be more fun
It can be confusing and saddening especially for other people, when they have to make the pipeline red all the time.
You could make the software development more rewarding by doing the same process, but without pipeline failures.
That could be reached by having a separate pipeline in a branch called api_publication, that when merged against just publishes a new api_client.
After you've manually upgraded the api_client version number in user_of_api_client, rebuilt it and adapted the user_of_api_client hash in runtime_app, the merge to the main branch should be successful on the first try.
